# How do I render a full body with skin using Kinect skeleton data?

Tags: render, kinect, xbox

Using the Kinect API I can get "skeleton" information,  how do I use this to render a full body with volume, skin a face, etc?

Comment: Check that link. You may find a suitable project: http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect

Comment: You can start looking at Sinbad Sample using OpenNI: Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zl6O-Rf52Co
Download: https://github.com/OpenNI/SampleAppSinbad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to avateering? Check out this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131041.aspx